# VS 2019 C++ console app gets parameters in UTF-8 instead of expected UTF-16LE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, utf-8

I'm building a new project in Visual Studio 2019. It's a console app that includes MFC headers. Here's the relevant code:

```
int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[]) // VS wrote "int main()", I added parameters myself.
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(nullptr);

    if (hModule != nullptr)
    {
        // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
        if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, nullptr, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
        {
            // TODO: code your application's behavior here.
            wprintf(L"Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n");
            nRetCode = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            nRetCode = MyFunction(argc, argv);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        wprintf(L"Fatal Error: GetModuleHandle failed\n");
        nRetCode = 1;
    }

    return nRetCode;
}
```

Most of this is boilerplate code generates by VS. I added parameters to the `main` function and the call to my own code, namely `MyFunction()`. It built just fine; didn't issue so much as a warning. On the very first test run I found that the text in argv[1] and argv[2] are in plain 8-bit ASCII or UTF-8. I was expecting UNICODE as UTF-16LE.
I do have the project properties set to use UNICODE. What have I done wrong to get command line parameters in UTF-8? Here's my setup in VS 2019:
[image: Properties dialog]

My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/using-wmain?view=msvc-160

Comment: @Eljay Thanks, that did it. I encourage you to post your comment as an answer. ;)

Comment: You're welcome.  Remy's got a good answer.  I'm not in it for the points, I'm just want to help people.  This is my third account, I've left 100k on the table with my previous 2 abandoned accounts.

Comment: I tried default project settings, I get ANSI as expected in `main`, but I don't get UTF-8.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I am unable to distinguish between ANSI and UTF-8 when only alphanumerics are present. If you have any tips on that, please let me know.

Comment: I used Unicode command line (for example, add `"Ελληνικά"` to exe's path name), then `MessageBoxA(0, GetCommandLineA(), 0, 0);` displays `"??????"`, because it doesn't support UTF-8, it just sees ANSI. Meanwhile, `MessageBoxW(0, GetCommandLineW(), 0, 0);` displays the text correctly. There is a way to enable UTF8 support, but it's experimental and it's not enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

[`main()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/main-function-and-program-execution) only works with `char` in the `argv[]` array.  If you want to use `wchar_t` instead, you need to rename `main()` to [`wmain()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/using-wmain) instead.

Or, since you are using `TCHAR`, you can rename `main()` to `_tmain()`, so that it will automatically map to `main()` in a MBCS build, and to `wmain()` in a Unicode build. See [What is difference between main and _tmain in Visual studio](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d5af4be-8baa-4ff1-bd65-21aefa049e4b)